# sum up certain variables (columns) by variable names

Tags: r, dplyr

i want to sum up certain variables (columns in a data frame).
I would like to select those variables by parts of their names.
The complex thing is that i have various conditions. So, using a single contains from dplyr does not work.

Here is an example:

```
ab_yy <- c(1:5)
bc_yy <- c(5:9)
cd_yy <- c(2:6)
de_xx <- c(3:7)

  ab_yy bc_yy cd_yy de_xx
1     1     5     2     3
2     2     6     3     4
3     3     7     4     5
4     4     8     5     6
5     5     9     6     7

dat <- data.frame(ab_yy,bc_yy,cd_yy,de_xx)  
#sum up all variables that contain yy and certain extra conditions
#may look something like this: rowSums(select(dat, contains(("yy&ab")|("yy&bc")) ) )
```

desired result:

> ```
> 6 8 10 12 14
> ```

Comment: use `matches` instead of `contains`

Comment: Try `select_if` with the desired function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it's the best way but u can do it like that with a grepl:

```
rowSums(dat[,grepl(pattern = "ab.*yy|bc.*yy",colnames(dat))==T])
```

Comment: Thx. Shorter one: rowSums(dat[,grepl("(ab|bc).*yy",names(dat))])

Comment: Yes nice this one is better ;)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Fixed, sorry, low on caffeine

If you want to use dplyr, try using `matches`:

```
    library(dplyr)
    dat %>%
      select(matches("*yy", )) %>%
      select(matches("ab*|bc*")) %>%
      rowSums(.)

[1]  6  8 10 12 14
```